# operation scoreboard function will not run every tick

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

When I try to run this function below called checklevelscore.mcfunction Inside of tick.mcfunction, it does not change the level score at all. I expect it to continuously add 1 to the "level" score if for example "brawnscore" is 1.

```
scoreboard players operation @a level += @s brawnscore
scoreboard players operation @a level += @s agilityscore
scoreboard players operation @a level += @s vigorscore 
scoreboard players operation @a level += @s individualityscore
```

checklevelscore.mcfunction works fine if I call it with /function ingame. The function just refuses to run every tick.

[example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ZQiyCOC5tnyuhB2k6HWnHcXcBAAh5MB/view?usp=sharing)

Would appreciate it greatly if y'all could help so I can stop beating my head against the wall. Thank you!

Comment: Ah yes, now I can actually understand it without spending an hour on it! :) I bet the issue is either inside `tick.json` or your folder structure is not right. Those would be good additions to the question. BTW, I have a dummy pack already [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19TRfBFKSt4DMvYeR93ahsvOcnGYBkoiC) that does something every tick, maybe that helps. (If it does, you can self-answer.)

Comment: @FabianRöling It looks like everything is structured correctly. If I change whatever is running every tick it does run, but again the function with the operation will not. Here is an [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ZQiyCOC5tnyuhB2k6HWnHcXcBAAh5MB/view?usp=sharing) of how my pack is.